# How can I move a Virtualbox window to another screen by keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, virtualbox

On Windows usually you can bring a window to another screen holding down the Windows-key and using the cursor keys. This does not work for Virtualbox windows.

So how can I bring the window to the current screen without using the mouse (e.g. when the other screen is detected but not visible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the window, however you need to make sure that the keypress is not consumed by the guest operating system.

Use Alt-Tab to set the focus onto the virtual machine. This window will immediately grab the keyboard, and subsequent keypresses are sent to the guest operating system. That is why you cannot switch back from it using Alt-Tab again.

You need to release the keyboard from the guest operating system by pressing the `Host Key Combination`. It is configurable but per default the `Right-Ctrl` key.

After you pressed that, you can use the Windows + cursor keys to position the window, or Alt-Tab to focus another window on the host operating system.